# Mac - PHP 5.6.31_7 Installed by Brew Install PHP56 Does not Include libphp5.so File

Tags: php, macos

I installed the PHP 5.6.31_7 using the `brew install php56`, `brew reinstall php56 --with-httpd24`, and `brew reinstall php56 --with-apache`; however, still I cannot find the `libexec` folder to make the necessary configuration in my `httpd.conf` file. Any solution is appreciated. I assume the config path should be something like `LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.31_7/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find the file in `/usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` if it installed successfully.

Comment: `/usr/local/opt/php56` folder structure follows the same pattern, and it is not there either :)

Comment: The brew formula for apache was recently renamed from httpd24 to httpd. Maybe try `brew reinstall php56 --with-httpd` ?